# Given a string, return n distinct characters with their respective counts, as well as the remainder of the string

Tags: python

Going through some old code, I found this function.

Given a string `carrier` and integer `nsyms`, it consumes `nsyms` distinct characters from the `carrier` string and returns a dictionary containing consumed characters and their respective counts, and the remainder of the `carrier` string.

```
def enc_consume(carrier, nsyms):
  chrs = defaultdict(int)

  i = 0  # see this?

  for i,c in enumerate(carrier):
    # `i` is not used in the loop
    chrs[c] += 1
    if len(chrs) == nsyms:
      break

  return chrs, carrier[i+1:]  # but it's used here
```

How would you rewrite this? I found the assignment `i = 0` confusing, since it was followed by a `for i...`, which will of course do the assignment as well.

---

**EDIT:** The point of the explicit assignment `i = 0` is that if `carrier` is empty, the loop will not execute. If it weren't for the assignment, `i` would be undefined by the time it is used in `return`.

Comment: Yes, the `i = 0` is effectively pointless because the name is reassigned on the next line.

Comment: It's not "effectively pointless", because if the assignment wasn't made, `i` would be out of scope by the time it is used in `return`. It's a local variable and its scope is limited to the `for` statement. After the `for`, it doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: It does still exist (just tried your function in Python 2.7 and 3.5, removing that assignment line, for my sanity). Perhaps Python should automatically trash `for` loop variables, but it doesn't.

Comment: You're right! I must have thought it was Go or something... In that case, this whole answer is pointless, since the assignment was the only thing I found confusing.

Comment: I was wondering based on your title. :) Still, I think something good came out of it, particularly in the answer you didn't choose: if you can, it's often good style to avoid using `break` and instead clearly define your condition by using a `while` loop rather than a pseudo-iteration ("go through it all... till I tell you to stop!")

Comment: Yes, and originally I did accept that answer. But I prefer to iterate over the elements of a sequence instead of incrementing a counter and retrieving an element in each iteration. Especially in interpreted languages, it can be quite inefficient.

Comment: Fair point! Python can be pretty weird about iteration, though. I haven't seen the `iter` function often enough to be sure how it works, but in the default `for element in container` loop, for example, it's just sugar for iterating through indexes and accessing the container with them — as can be seen in the horrifying example `L = ['a', 'b', 'c']; for c in L: print(c, end=''); L.remove(c)`, where your output will be `ac`!

Comment: It's not just sugar, it's implemented in C. Compare `timeit('for e in seq: e', 'seq=list(range(100))')` and `timeit('for i in range(len(seq)): seq[i]', 'seq=list(range(100))')`. On my machine the first is ~2.7x faster.

Comment: True. My mistake.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would avoid using indexes altogether and rely on `iter` to advance character by character and remember what's left in the string:

```
def enc_consume(carrier, nsyms):
    characters = defaultdict(int)
    stream = iter(carrier)

    for char in stream:
        characters[char] += 1
        if len(characters) >= nsyms:
             break

    return characters, ''.join(stream)
```

Comment: Very elegant solution! As per looks. I wondered what the performance implications of `''.join(stream)` were, since the carrier string can be thousands of characters long. A quick test with a string of length 65536 advanced by 10 characters shows it takes ~2000 times longer than returning a substring. However, to make the substring, you need the current position. That means you cannot avoid using an index, or can you? Yes, using the `__length_hint__` method of the iterator. It's called "hint", but for underlying sequences with `__len__` method, it returns exact length of the remaining part.

Comment: @kyrill Just tried it, with `len(a)` of 65536: `%timeit enc_consume(a, 10)` `10 loops, best of 3: 49 ms per loop` and `%timeit enc_consume2(a, 10)` `10 loops, best of 3: 40.2 ms per loop`. Version 2 being the one with `join`.

Comment: What interpreter? I use CPython 3.5.1 on linux and the join-version is definitely order of magnitude slower.

Comment: @kyrill This was IPython 5.1.0 running Python 3.6.0 on windows. When I get the chance, I'll try on your setup as well.

Comment: @kyrill Silly me, `a` don't have 10 different characters... So yeah, pretty much crap on speed.

Answer (score 7):

```
def enc_consume(carrier, nsyms):
    first_unused_idx = 0
    char_cnt = defaultdict(int)
    while first_unused_idx < len(carrier) and len(char_cnt) < nsyms:
        char_cnt[carrier[first_unused_idx]] += 1
        first_unused_idx += 1 
    return char_cnt, carrier[first_unused_idx:]
```

I'd suggest using a `while` loop here because it would make declaring the counter outside the loop natural and the number of iterations is not known beforehand (which is a common use case for a while loop).

Answer (score 5):

Instead of a `defaultdict(int)`, consider using a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead.  The code in this function would otherwise be identical, but the `Counter` would more clearly convey your intentions.  Furthermore, `Counter` methods such as [`.most_common()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) might be useful to the caller.